# Handling a domain exception happened during template evaluation

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm designing an error page for a particular exception type.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>xxx.AbstractConfigurableNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/xxx/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

I am using OmniFaces and their exception factory to handle errors.

```
<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandler</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

`AbstractConfigurable` is a domain class and its instance is being created during template evaluation*. The constructor of `AbstractConfigurable` may throw an `AbstractConfigurableNotFoundException`. When it does, this exception gets wrapped into template-specific exceptions as a cause.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    Caused by: javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException
         Caused by: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException
              ...
                   Caused by: xxx.AbstractConfigurableNotFoundException
```

As a result, a different exception type comes out and my `<error-page>` logic isn't applied.

Obviously, I don't want to handle, `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException`

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException</exception-type>
    <location>/xxx/page-not-found.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

but I'd like to handle any exception with an `AbstractConfigurableNotFoundException` as a cause.

Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: This is a really strange example. Custom exception wrapped in a NFE which is in turn wrapped in an IAE. I hope it's just an example? And, I'm confused why you configured an error page location while you're using the `FacesMessageExceptionHandler` instead of `FullAjaxExceptionHandler`. Which one are you really using? The latter has according to its javadoc a `org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP` which could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` supports a context parameter to set fully qualified names of exception types to unwrap. Below is an extract of relevance from its [documentation](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler):

> #### Configuration
>
> By default only [`FacesException`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/FacesException.html?is-external=true) and [`ELException`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/el/ELException.html?is-external=true) are unwrapped. You can supply a context parameter ["org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP"](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.3/org/omnifaces/exceptionhandler/FullAjaxExceptionHandler.html#PARAM_NAME_EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP) to specify additional exception types to unwrap. The context parameter value must be a commaseparated string of fully qualified names of additional exception types. Note that this also covers subclasses of specified exception types.
>
> ```
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP</param-name>
>     <param-value>javax.ejb.EJBException,javax.persistence.RollbackException</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> This context parameter will also be read and used by [`FacesExceptionFilter`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.3/org/omnifaces/filter/FacesExceptionFilter.html).

So, in your specific case you could use the following configuration in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.EXCEPTION_TYPES_TO_UNWRAP</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Note that `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagAttributeException` extends from `FacesException`, which is by default already unwrapped, so you don't really need to specify this along.

Comment: It was a strange example, indeed... Updated with the real stacktrace. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Right. Answer also updated accordingly. In next questions please don't obfuscate code/logic/behavior which is beyond your control. It would make the question potentially really confusing to experts.